# How to detect any click on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to catch the click event on any elements of the page. But I can not catch a click on a specific page elements. See example https://jsfiddle.net/rdnf5m1f/

```
 $(function() {
        $(".profile").on( "click","a", function() {
            console.log(1);
          return false;
        });

        // below not work
        $("body").on( "click","*", function() {
            console.log(2);
        });

        $("body").click(function() {
            console.log(2);
        });

        $(window).click(function() {
            console.log(2);
        });
 });
```

Why?

Comment: Try wrapping that code in `$(function(){ // your code });`

Comment: do not laugh at me. just try it

Answer (score 3):

Following what you need by "Capture all, Except some". Add a class 'nocapture' to the elements that you don't want to capture, and use the script:

```
jQuery('*:not(.nocapture)').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Element clicked', this); 
})
```

Comment: This is a copy of an answer that i wrote a few days ago

Comment: This might add thousands of event listeners to a page though.

Comment: Many event listeners its problem? Why? I tried jQuery('*') and at first sight works well.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return false` from a jQuery function, it executes `stopPropagation`, which will prevent other handlers from executing.  In this case I think you're looking for the following code.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  console.log(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in some kind of ready handler like `document`.

```
$(function() {
    $("body").click(function() {
        console.log(2);
    });
});
```

[Check this out](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.target` properties to exclude a certain element type or class.

```
var tagsToExclude = 'a,div';
$(document).click(function(e) {   
   if(tagsToExclude.indexOf(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()) == -1)
       alert('Clicked');
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/rdnf5m1f/4/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="profile">
    <a href="">Bla bla bla</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on( "click", function() {

  alert("click");

});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/rdnf5m1f/3/)**